# Strange behaviour from file_exists

Tags: php

I am having trouble checking if an image exists or not I have tried using file_exists but always get a false response from it.

```
$fjpg = $code . ".jpg";
$imurl = "producers/$dir/images/$fjpg";
if(file_exists($imurl))
{

$cimage = <<<end
    <a href="$imurl"><span style="color:#990000;"><b>$code</b></span>:&nbsp; $desc</a></div></td>
    end;
    }
    $cimage = <<<end
    <span style="color:#990000;"><b>$code</b></span>:&nbsp; $desc</div></td>
    end;
```

The heredoc is just there due to my growing frustration. I have got end; with no spaces in front of it in the actual file. What is more perplexing is that in the same file working fine is the following

```
<?
if (file_exists("producers/$dir/header.php")) {
    include("producers/$dir/header.php");
}
?>
```

I have tried using is_file with the same results.
I have swapped the two statements around and used the link provided to get to the file so my assumption is that $imurl gives a workable path just not one that file_exists needs. 
I have used `echo getcwd();` as Jompper suggested and get
 /home/caliver/public_html/figures

Comment: Can you please show us your directory structure and from which file are you calling this piece of code?

Comment: Most likely an issue with your relative path. Have you tried checking the absolute path to the file? If that works, then you'll have to adjust the relative path that's trying to reference it.

Comment: What happens when you print out $imurl? What does it read?

Comment: @Dan: didn't that indentation edits affect the heredoc behavior?

Comment: `echo getcwd();` to see your current path the location is relative to

Comment: ok the `echo getcwd();` gives me /home/caliver/public_html/figures with the files I am looking for residing in /home/caliver/public_html/figures/producers/$dir/images

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use the server document root:

```
$doc_root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

if (file_exists($doc_root . "/" . $imurl)) {
```

Comment: OK I have just tried this and I am still getting false. So I duplicated the working file_exists query `if(file_exists("producers/$dir/header.php"))`
the only real difference between the two is in a large while loop.

Comment: Yes $dir is set it is used several times in the code and each time it seems to work. However I could make sure it is set at the beginning of the while loop and see what happens!

Comment: Using the code above, does echo $doc_root . "/" . $imurl actually return the path of a file that definitely exists?

Comment: yes just tried it and got
/home/caliver/public_html/producers/battbuild/images/GR01.jpg 
this is definitely a file.

Comment: Just asking because your filename comes back as GR01.jpg - you know that file_exists is case sensitive, right? If your actual file is gr01.jpg it will fail.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what to tell you then fella, I'm using file_exists on one of my sites to do exactly what you are doing with no problems. The only other thing I can think of is that it's a permissions issue...

Answer (score 0):

OK The answer to this problem is that **$cimage** should be defined before the **if** statement or an **else** should have been used. I had become blinded to the obvious coding error and had decided the often awkward **file_exists** must have been the problem. Thanks for the many suggestions guys.